# What XML structure matches this XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XPath and I dont understand it very well. What would the xml file structure look like?

```
/child::p/child::c[preceding-sibling::* = following-sibling::* and preceding-sibling::* != following-sibling::*]
```

Answer (score 1):

well it's quite odd xpath.

Here is document

```
<p>
<d>x</d>
<d>1</d>
<c>d</c>
<p>x</p>
<d>2</d>
</p>
```

and

```
<c>d</c>
```

is matched by your xpath.

Comment: whats weird is this will select the same node `/child::p/child::c[preceding-sibling::* != following-sibling::*]`

Comment: /child::p/child::c = Which node you want.
[preceding-sibling::* = following-sibling::* and preceding-sibling::* != following-sibling::*] this is condition which must be fulfilled.
Wish good luck tomorrow

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp
http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
child::c[preceding-sibling::* = following-sibling::* and preceding-sibling::* != following-sibling::*]
```

means "look for a child element `c` with a preceding-sibling value that is equal to `c`'s following-sibling value and also has a preceding-sibling value that is not equal to its following-sibling value.

In the given XML above,

```
<p>
<d>x</d>
<d>1</d>
<c>d</c>
<p>x</p>
<d>2</d>
</p>
```

applying the xpath would result in

```
<c>d</c>
```

because the condition `preceding-sibling::* = following-sibling::*` (in this case `<d>x</d>` and `<p>x</p>` respectively) is satisfied and the condition `preceding-sibling::* != following-sibling::*` is also satisfied (preceding-sibling values: `x` and `1`; following-sibling values: `x` and `2`). If you remove the preceding-sibling `<d>x</d>` form the XML above, that is:

```
<p>
<d>1</d>
<c>d</c>
<p>x</p>
<d>2</d>
</p>
```

you will get no output.

Comment: I would correct that paraphrase to: "look for a child element p with a child element c where some preceding-sibling value of c compares equal to some following-sibling value of c, and some preceding-sibling value of c compares not equal to some following-sibling of c.

Comment: @MichaelKay, much better. I'm in a struggle to find the exact words to say.